# Microsoft word saved file not found

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, microsoft-word

I not understanding how this question should be tilted. 
I am using HP Laptop with Dual Core 2.5GH Processor and   2GB RAM. Windows 8 operating system, 64 bit. Microsoft office 13 has installed. My HD disk has three partition, C(windows), D and another named Project and some other place has remained allocated.

For class quiz test i had made a Microsoft word file. In the file i noted from book for my Quiz test and saved in a folder in D Drive by name "Networking CT 1 Note". I had seen that the file has saved correctly and shut downed my laptop.

Now my problem is that when i searching the file for printing, i am not finding it. Then i open Microsoft word and in "File > Open" option i see recent files list, i saw my file there but it is showing a different path "F:\1503\CSE_311-Compute Networking\CSE 311\Networking CT 1 Note.docx". The folder name is right but the drive name is different.  I have no drive called "F".I saved it in same path Just the drive was "D". When i clicked on it it is showing a message that the directory name is not valid. Yes, it should  show  the warning cause i have no drive called "F".

Another problem is that some of my favorite links referred to this Drive D is not working they also showing that it has referred to drive F which is not available.Then delete these links and remake the links then it is working.

Now i want to know why this have happened and is there any way to recover the file. I have spent a lot of time on it.

Comment: You didn't save where you thought you did. From the name it looks like it was saved on a campus networked drive and you are no longer connected to the campus network. If you go back to the campus and connect to the network you may be able to find your document.

Comment: @DavidPostil no it is my personal pc at home. Our campus network is not available out of campus. Another problem is that some of my favorite links referred to this Drive is not working they also showing that it has referred to drive F which is not available.